# SQL Server : One to Many output to single row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working on a nightly trigger for failed jobs in one of our utility servers. The system writes the basic info on the job to the `WQ` table, and the details of it to the `WDQ` table. The `WQ`table will have one entry per job, while the `WDQ` table will have about 4-5 entries for the same job.

If I pull the data using a basic join like this:

```
select 
    wq.id, wq.Name, wq.Server, wq.DB, wq.insertdate, 
    wq.CreatedDate as 'Completed Date/Time', 
    wq.PeekedService, wdq.Op, wdq.Val
from 
    milan.milan.WorkspaceQueue wq (nolock)
inner join 
    milan.milan.WorkspaceDetailQueue wdq (nolock) on wq.Id = wdq.PId
where 
    wq.OpDescription = 'Manage My Matters'
    and wq.Id = '5114'
order by 
    wq.InsertDate desc
```

I get data like this, which is repeating the `WDQ` data multiple times.

```
id|Description|Server|DB|insertdate|Completed Date/Time|PeekedService|Op|Val
5114|User:  CHAND|DMS-WEST|SFO|2018-04-12 19:25:00|2018-04-12 19:29:00|My Matters Service 09|mymattersorganize|NULL
5114|User:  CHAND|DMS-WEST|SFO|2018-04-12 19:25:00|2018-04-12 19:29:00|My Matters Service 09|folderid|40310
5114|User:  CHAND|DMS-WEST|SFO|2018-04-12 19:25:00|2018-04-12 19:29:00|My Matters Service 09|categoryformat|@imProfileCustom1@ - @imProfileCustom1Description@
5114|User:  CHAND|DMS-WEST|SFO|2018-04-12 19:25:00|2018-04-12 19:29:00|My Matters Service 09|workspaceformat|@imProfileDescription@ - @imProfileName@
```

Essentially, I'd like to have the resulting data look something like this instead:

```
id|Description|Server|DB|insertdate|Completed Date/Time|PeekedService|PrjID|CategoryFormat|WorkspaceFormat
5114|User:  CHAND|DMS-WEST|SFO|2018-04-12 19:25:00|2018-04-12 19:29:00|My Matters Service 09|40310|@imProfileCustom1@ - @imProfileCustom1Description@|@imProfileDescription@ - @imProfileName@
```

Comment: I would urge you to read what you posted and ask yourself if you think you could honestly provide an answer based on what is posted. Maybe you want to look at PIVOT. Perhaps even a dynamic PIVOT? I would also urge you to read this article before you continue littering your queries with nolock. https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/ It is far more sinister than most people realize.

Comment: Looking at this close is looks like maybe what you really need is here is conditional aggregation. But it is so hard to decipher the data and output. Here is a great article that provides some nice ways of presenting this type of stuff. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: @SeanLange, I've totally co-opted that spaghettidba link and am peppering SO with it. +1, retroactively, since I stole it from your comments.

Comment: Nice. I am sure that Gianluca will appreciate the traffic to his blog.